# how to accumulate promise return inside a loop

Tags: loops, recursion, promise

for example am trying to recursively get the file size of all items under a folder in cordova so i have something like

```
getDirSize(path) {
    return this.listDir(path).then((data) => {
        let size = 0

        data.dirs.map((dir) => {
            size += this.getRecursiveSize(dir.files)
        })

        if (data.files.length) {
            size += this.getRecursiveSize(data.files)
        }

        return size
    })
}

getRecursiveSize(files) {
    let size = 0

    files.map((item) => {
        this.getFileMeta(item.url).then((file) => {
            size += file.size
        })

        if (item.files) {
            size += this.getRecursiveSize(item.files)
        }
    })

    return size
}
```

which is called through

```
getDirSize(path).then((size) => {
    console.log(size)
})
```

however this doesn't work because the `getFileMeta()` is a promise, i know about `promise.all()` but am not sure how to use it properly to get the final size of all items.

Comment: Start by not using `forEach`.

Comment: You can't actually write a function that returns the size.  You need to return a promise, because if the results of getFileMeta aren't immediately available, then they will have to be calculated *after* your function returns.

Comment: @MattTimmermans can u add an example ?

Comment: You now use `map`, but you don't actually `return` anything useful from the callback, and you don't do anything with the array of results.

Answer (score 0):

So you can put all of the calls to getFileMeta() into an array using map and Promise.all. Promise.all will take a an array of promises and set whatever is resolved within each into an array.

So you get back an array of fileMetaData in this case, which you can use as any other array (after the Promise.all is finished -- using .then or await)..

If it (aka getFileMeta) already returns a promise:

```
const filesMetaData = Promise.all(files.map(file => this.getFileMeta(file.url)))
filesMetaData.then(
fileMetaData // became an array here because of Promise.all
=> fileMetaData.reduce((accumulatedSize, file) => {
  accumulatedSize += file.size
  return accumulatedSize
})
```

Or if you are using a later version of node then you can use asynchronous javascript with `async/await` which is pretty cool!

In pseudo-code the strategy is:

1. Await getting the fileMetaData about EACH one of the files.
2. Get each one of the original files' sizes and add those to 0.
3. Check for if any files have nested files within.
4. If so add those files to a list of files to recursively run this function.
5. If none of the files have nested files return the count for the parent files.

```js
const recursivelyGetSize = async (files) => {
  if (!files.length) { // recursive condition 
    return 0
  }
  const filesMetaData = await Promise.all(
    files.map(file => this.getFileMeta(file.url))
  ) // became an array of files here because of Promise.all
  const count = fileMetaData.reduce(
    (accumulatedSize, file) => accumulatedSize + file.size,
    0
  )
  const filesWithFiles = filesMetaData.filter(file => file.files.length)
  if (!filesWithFiles.length) {
    return count
  }
  // not sure if you need await here because
  // return by default has a built in await
  return count + await recursivelyGetSize([
      ...filesWithFiles.map(file => file.files)
    ])
}
```

Comment: **Also not sure if when you say getFileMeta is a promise if it returns a promise or what**, yes it does, also can u plz update the example with the recursive condition ?

Comment: arrow functions have a lexical `this` so there's no need to use `_this` in your second example

Comment: does this work? I think it should or it might need slight tweaking

Comment: hi I think I had updated it to give you the full recursive version. Let me know if ther were issues.

Comment: @Zargold sorry for the delay i just saw ur comment now, thanx for the update, can we a recursive check inside the `files.map` as well ?